# What does the abbreviation "p.e." mean?

Tags: terminology, circular-statistics, abbreviation

I came across a paper that uses the abbreviation "p.e.":

[Khatri and Mardia, The Von Mises-Fisher Matrix Distribution in Orientation Statistics. 1976.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2984884)

It's in Section 7 on page 105. I'm including a short excerpt:

> Using the density function of $K^{\frac{1}{2}}XX'K^{\frac{1}{2}} = S$ given in Khatri (1975a), we find that the p.e. $X$ given $XX'=I_n$ is

What does the abbreviation "p.e." mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means probability element.

This paragraph is taken from the following book chapter: [Order Statistics](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1948-54-01/S0002-9904-1948-08936-4/S0002-9904-1948-08936-4.pdf)

> If $X$ is such that the probability $X\leq x$ is $F(x)$, or briefly if 
>   $$
> Pr(X\leq x)=F(x),
> $$
>
> then we say that $X$ is a *random variable* which has the cdf $F(x)$. If $F(x)$ has a continuous derivative $f(x)$, then $f(x)dx$ is called the *probability element* of $X$, and $f(x)$ the *probability density function* (pdf) of $X$.

I think it would have something to do with measure theory as well. Going over a Probability Theory course might help too.

Comment: So does this mean that the paper should have referred to "the p.e. of $X$" instead of "the p.e. $X$"?

Comment: @amcnabb Sounds like so. The paper your were reading used the notation p.e. on page 97 as well: "... we find that the joint p.e. (probability element) of Y and X1 is ... ".

Comment: I missed the earlier reference. Thanks for finding it.